# 2 of 4 System.Threading.Timers don't start on the server, but runs fine locally

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a relatively simple console application. In the `Main`-method I have the following code:

```
TimeSpan immediately = TimeSpan.Zero;

var userRoutine = new System.Threading.Timer(
    o => SyncUsers(o), null, immediately, userMatchFrequency);
var materialRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncMaterials(o), null, immediately, materialSyncFrequency);
var activityRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncActivities(o), null, immediately, activitySyncFrequency);
var customerRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncCustomers(o), null, immediately, customerSyncFrequency);
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
```

And in the start of all the callback methods I have a `Console.WriteLine(string)` with a unique message on the very first line.

I've then cleaned and rebuilt it in Visual Studio, then copied the bin->Release folder. When I run the .exe file locally, it works fine. But when my boss runs it on the server, I can see that it only starts the last two Timers. And it does so consistently.

The project is targeted .NET 4.5.2 and that's the latest the server supports, so I doubt it's related to that. All I've been able to find on it, is that I should keep a reference to all timers in the scope of the running thread, to avoid garbage collection. But to the best of my knowledge, the blocking `Console.ReadKey()`-call in a while loop doesn't make the outside scope "collectible" to the GC.

I don't have the luxury of testing a lot of hit and miss theories, so I'm probably going abandon Timers and use `Task`s that I manage manually - but I'm still curious what could be going on here.

Comment: Do you have install .net 4.5 on server ?

Comment: @LinhTuan Yes, that's what I meant by "that's the latest the server supports".

Comment: I see no reason why your code shouldn't work. Is it possible to test on other machines than your server?

Comment: @cwap Sure, it runs fine on my local computer and I have a server on the local network I can test it with. It works both places though, but currently they both run with 4.6. I don't know the exact version installed on the production server, nor do I have access to it - and my boss is a busy guy, so I won't be able to get that info promptly. He says 4.5 is installed on it though, and I have other applications with 4.5.2 running on it currently. Do you think it's related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But to the best of my knowledge, the blocking Console.ReadKey()-call in a while loop doesn't make the outside scope "collectible" to the GC.

That is not true. You don't use your local variables in any way, so nothing prevents GC from collecting them (though in Debug mode or when you run with debugger attached - measures might be taken to prevent that, but not in Release mode without debugger). It's easy to check with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    TimeSpan immediately = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var userMatchFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var materialSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    var activitySyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    var customerSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    var userRoutine = new System.Threading.Timer(
        o => SyncUsers(o), null, immediately, userMatchFrequency);
    var materialRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncMaterials(o), null, immediately, materialSyncFrequency);
    var activityRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncActivities(o), null, immediately, activitySyncFrequency);
    var customerRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncCustomers(o), null, immediately, customerSyncFrequency);

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}

static void SyncUsers(object o) {
    Console.WriteLine("Sync users");
}

static void SyncMaterials(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sync meterials");
}

static void SyncActivities(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sync activities");
}

static void SyncCustomers(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sync customers");
}
```

If you compile this in Release mode and run without debugger - you won't see any messages in console at all, because all your timers will be immediately garbage collected. To solve this problem - use `GC.KeepAlive`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    TimeSpan immediately = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var userMatchFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var materialSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    var activitySyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    var customerSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    var userRoutine = new System.Threading.Timer(
        o => SyncUsers(o), null, immediately, userMatchFrequency);
    var materialRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncMaterials(o), null, immediately, materialSyncFrequency);
    var activityRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncActivities(o), null, immediately, activitySyncFrequency);
    var customerRoutine = new Timer(
        o => SyncCustomers(o), null, immediately, customerSyncFrequency);

    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.ReadKey(false);

    GC.KeepAlive(userRoutine);
    GC.KeepAlive(materialRoutine);
    GC.KeepAlive(activityRoutine);
    GC.KeepAlive(customerRoutine);
}
```

Or better - dispose your timers after `Console.ReadKey` (or wrap in using):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    TimeSpan immediately = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var userMatchFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var materialSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    var activitySyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    var customerSyncFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    using (new Timer(o => SyncUsers(o), null, immediately, userMatchFrequency))
    using (new Timer(o => SyncMaterials(o), null, immediately, materialSyncFrequency))
    using (new Timer(o => SyncActivities(o), null, immediately, activitySyncFrequency))
    using (new Timer(o => SyncCustomers(o), null, immediately, customerSyncFrequency))
         Console.ReadKey(false);                    
}
```

Timers implement `IDisposable` and it's a good practice to dispose everything that implements it anyway. This will also prevent their garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of how to test it. I wasn't aware of the `GC` class. Given this, I might actually give Timers another go.

Comment: @Evk - strange coincidence - I was just getting to the same reasoning about putting the timers in `using`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess that's because it's the most natural way to go in this case :)

Comment: I tested it out, and you were right. I persuaded my boss to give it a go and it ran perfectly, so this must have been the issue. Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Evk for pointing this out. I upvoted both answers and accepted Evk's answer because he originally showcased how to test that the GC was indeed able to remove the variables I thought were safe. And I also appreciate mentioning that Timer is disposable, which I had neither realized. Even though it obviously isn't necessary to solve the issue, it's still good to know. I definitely need to brush up on this stuff in an upcoming weekend.

Answer (score 3):

GC is far more aggressive than you imagine. E.g. an object can be collected whilst its *constructor* is still running, provided that the remaining part of the constructor doesn't access any of the object's fields. Variable *scope* is not related to variable *lifetime*.

If you now are more suspicious of GC (and you should be), you can verify this supposition by adding some [`GC.KeepAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx)s:

```
TimeSpan immediately = TimeSpan.Zero;

var userRoutine = new System.Threading.Timer(
    o => SyncUsers(o), null, immediately, userMatchFrequency);
var materialRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncMaterials(o), null, immediately, materialSyncFrequency);
var activityRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncActivities(o), null, immediately, activitySyncFrequency);
var customerRoutine = new Timer(
    o => SyncCustomers(o), null, immediately, customerSyncFrequency);
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
GC.KeepAlive(userRoutine);
GC.KeepAlive(materialRoutine);
GC.KeepAlive(activityRoutine);
GC.KeepAlive(customerRoutine);
```

Though I'd generally look to restructure the application after this point so that the references are kept alive in a more organic fashion, having verified that it is a GC issue.

Comment: Those 4 lines are unreachable code, so I imagine you mean for me to call them before the while loop. And by "organic fashion" you mean e.g. via tasks, callbacks and sleeping threads?

Comment: `GC.KeepAlive` is an artificial method that *doesn't do anything*. All it does is make it seem like your variables are going to be accessed later. You need those calls *somewhere* later than your `Console.ReadKey` line if you want those variables to keep their objects alive whilst that method is running.

Comment: @AskeB. - I've also added a link to that method - the description is "References the specified object, which makes it ineligible for garbage collection from the start of the current routine to the point *where this method is called.*" (My emphasis)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how `GC.KeepAlive` works. My assumptions were wrong on how it worked. Regardless, they should still be called within the while(true) loop for the compile to include them, I imagine.

Comment: @AskeB. - I'd imagined that this was just stub-code for testing for the time being - i.e. there's not much point, in the final released code, to just sit in an infinite loop calling `Console.ReadLine`. Also, since timers are disposable, you might consider putting them inside `using` statements and putting loop inside those. Since, then `Dispose` will be called after the loop "finishes", the references are kept alive "organically" and the compiler shouldn't complain.